# Thread 1 fatal error on tableViewCell button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to add a follow/following button to all the cells of a tableviewcell (linked to the users the current user is following - similar to the instagram followers list).

The code runs but when i click on the followers button to take me to the table view I keep getting an error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" - would appreciate any help to let me know what i am doing wrong.

Code in table view cell:

```
@IBOutlet weak var followersFollowButton: UIButton!

var user: UserModel? {
    didSet {
        updateView()
    }
}
func updateView() {
     if user!.isFollowing! {
        configureUnFollowButton()
    } else {
        configureFollowButton()
    }
}
```

code in view controller:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var users: [UserModel] = []

func loadusers() {

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    let followersRef = ref.child("followers").child(currentUser) //retreives all nodes in the following node
    followersRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot.children.allObjects)
        for child in snapshot.children { //build the array of keys
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key

            let userRef = ref.child("users").child(key) //get the user name and profile image from the users node
            userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                let user = UserModel()
                user.fullname = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "fullname").value as? String
                user.profileImageUrl = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "profileImageUrl").value as? String

  //line below is where i am getting the error
                self.isFollowing(userId: user.id!, completed: { (value) in 
                    user.isFollowing = value
                    self.users.append(user)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            })
        }
    })
}

func isFollowing(userId: String, completed: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    Api.Follow.isFollowing(userId: userId, completed: completed)
}
```

code in follow Api:

```
var REF_FOLLOWERS = Database.database().reference().child("followers")

func isFollowing(userId: String, completed: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    REF_FOLLOWERS.child(userId).child(Api.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
        snapshot in
        if let _ = snapshot.value as? NSNull {
            completed(false)
        } else {
            completed(true)
        }
    })
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `user.id` must be nil. Don't force-unwrap nil values.

Answer (score 0):

You're force-unwrapping an optional value which contains `nil`.

You should be using `if let` or `guard let` statements in your `updateView()` function.

Furthermore `let snap = child as! DataSnapshot` can fail, as can `user.id!` in the event of a `nil` value (which is what is happening with the latter, given that error message and your comment). You should rewrite these to safely handle `nil` value-cases.

Best practice is to avoid the force-unwrap/bang operator (`!`) at all costs.